# Connectivity of a random graph

Tags: connectedness, random-graphs

I am wondering whether a $k$-regular graph of size $n$ is connected. $k$ in my case is 8 and $n$ is ~3500. Any way of calculating the probability of such a graph not being connected?

Comment: To get a probability you'll have to specify a distribution.

Comment: I expect this probability to be quite low anyway, so I guess a uniform distribution for an edge to be picked might be a way to get an upper bound on the probability of being disconnected.

Comment: Wikipedia has some useful things to say on [random regular graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_regular_graph). Clearly, as usual with anything about graphs, Bollobas is the one to look at.

Comment: What's "a uniform distribution for an edge to be picked"?